# Mocking an object for unit testing in Jasmine without using Require

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write specs for a JavaScript file (say 'functionality.js'). jQuery is the only external library used. I am using Karma as my test runner.

functionality.js in-turn refers to an object (say 'FOO') which is defined in a different file on which several methods are defined. The object FOO (and its methods) is used in several other files. I don't want to add in foo.js (where FOO is defined) to the list of files in Karma because that in turn makes use an object defined elsewhere and so on. I would like to be able to test functionality.js and others in isolation by mocking FOO as an empty object and be able to commonly use it in all my spec files. Would I be able to do that? Are there any other alternate patterns to this?

My trials: I tried creating a helper file and defined an empty FOO object wrapped in an IIFE, then added that file to Karma before I loaded my source JavaScript files, but it throws a ReferenceError saying can't find variable FOO in functionality.js:1

Comment: If you defined your mock `FOO` object in an IIFE, it won't be available to other objects. You'd need to create it on the global scope. Also, you should show the code that you're having trouble with

Comment: Thanks @Phil, it sure works when it is created in the global scope but my concern is that it will interfere with the original definition of FOO. Is there a general pattern for this kind of a scenario? Where you'd create a dummy object instead of the tested file's dependency?